# How to split two consecutive brackets?

Tags: java, split

Imagine that I have a string `((3 * 5) * (2 * 23))` and as a string array `[((3, *, 5), *, (2, *, 23))]`. I want to separate the first two brackets in order to get `"("`, `"(3"`. Split function isn't working in this case, it is returning an empty string.

Comment: You may find a solution for this very problem, but regex are not a tool for language parsing. Finite-state automates are more appropriate.

Comment: I know that this situation is better if using finite-state automates, i just don't know how to do it, so I think im complicating this a lot...

Comment: What are you trying to do with this data? What kind of output are you expecting given your input of `((3 * 5) * (2 * 23))`.

Comment: the result of the arithmetic expression

Comment: Regex are exactly a tool for parsing languages -- that's basically all they do -- and they are identical in power to finite state automata. The only problem is that this language is not regular :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your probably looking for is `(?=X)` or `(?<=X)` which split before or after X, but still capture X in the string. The exact choice on how to use these is up to you. Since you specified `"("` and `"(3"` you'll probably want to start with this:

```
str.split("(?<=[)])|(?=[(])|\\s+");
```

Which gets any string ending in ), any string beginning in (, and also removes spaces. But the look-behind or look-ahead seems to interfere with the spacing, so you can add a bit to look for spaces associated with each parenthesis, and not keep them by replacing `=` with `!`. I.e.

```
str.split("(?<=[)])(?!\\s)|(?<!\\s)(?=[(])|\\s+");
```

Now this is all a lot to take in so take in and I don't think strings like `"(3"` are going to go over well when you try to start evaluating this, so you'll probably want to tweak it even further. Consequently you might want to check out the [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) for examples and [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for references to all the various patterns.

Comment: Nice answer, I'll look into it

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do, is not splitting your text, but create something which allows you to parse it.
Here is simple example of code which helps you to achieve your final goal. I don't recommend you to use it, but i hope it will give you idea in which direction you need to go:

public class Lime {

```
static enum TokenType{
    LEFT_BRACKET,RIGHT_BRACKET,NUMBER,OPERATOR
}

static interface Token {
    TokenType getType();
    String getValue();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String expr = "((3*5)*(2*23))";
    System.out.println(parse(expr));

}

private static String parse(String expr) {
    Token[] tokens = getTokens(expr);
    Stack<Token> stack = new Stack<Token>();
    for (Token token : tokens) {

        if (token.getType()==TokenType.NUMBER && !stack.isEmpty() && token.getType()==TokenType.OPERATOR) {
            stack.push(eval(token, stack.pop(), stack.pop()));
        } else if (token.equals(")")) {
            token = stack.pop();
            stack.pop();
            if (token.getType()==TokenType.NUMBER  && !stack.isEmpty() && isOp(stack.peek())) {
                stack.push(eval(token, stack.pop(), stack.pop()));
            } else {
                stack.push(token);
            }
        } else {
            stack.push(token);
        }
    }
    return stack.pop().getValue();
}



private static Token eval(Token a, Token operator, Token b) {
    switch (operator.getValue()) {
    case "*":
        return createNumberToken((Integer.parseInt(a.getValue()) * Integer.parseInt(b.getValue())));
    }
    //
    return null;
}
 private static Token[] getTokens(String expr) {
        // TODO to be implemented
        return null;
    }
private static Token createNumberToken(int i) {
    // TODO to be implemented
    return null;
}
```

}

To not give you solution on plate, I left methods which creates tokens unimplemented. This should give you brief idea what your homework is about. I also recommend you to read about [Interpreter Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern)

Comment: This is really misleading. Your slipping extra spaces into your equation `"( ( 3 ...` instead of `"((3...` and splitting over spaces, but then telling OP "What you need to do, is not splitting your text..." Of course he needs to *parse* it, and splitting is only a convenient first step to that end. But, if want to give an answer without splitting then give an answer without `split()`.

Comment: @Linus I coded it to show direction where he should go rather than final solution. I added additional empty spaces to simplify my solution, and make it more readable, and as it is homework, I think it is better to provide solution which gives op idea what he need to do than fully working solution on plate

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is can you explain then how he should do it without splitting the string (I don't mean you need to code it for him). I surely agree on the homework-part, but your telling him not to something which you are doing yourself, if only for example.

Comment: @Linus i see your point, i changed my code, and left two key methods unimplemented

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different approaches to a problem like this. Here is one attempt that does not involve any type of parsing of the original string. This is also assuming that the String is a valid expression.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Solution {           
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException{
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");  //Create a script engine
        String expression = "((3 * 5) * (2 * 23))";
        System.out.println(engine.eval(expression));

        //or you can do it in one line
        System.out.println(new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript").eval(expression));
    }
}
```

This utilizes the built in JavaScript engine to do the evaluation for you. Hope this helps!

Comment: this is a homework and i cannot use functions like eval! but thanks for the answer

Comment: @pMpC in that case I would take a step back and think of a way to represent the same data differently so that you can evaluate. Some topics that come in mind are [Shunting yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) and [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). They seem complicated at first but once you can implement the algorithms, it is a piece of cake.

Comment: @pMpC no worries. I know it isn't much but I would just stay away from trying to think of a way to parse the data yourself and instead focus on a way to represent the data you have with something you can actually work with.